# find and replace string in nested json table (MySql)

Tags: mysql, replace, phpmyadmin

I have a problem Ive been trying to solve but unfortunately unable to. I have a nested json data in a column called "fields" as such :

```
{"15":{"name":"field1","value":"http:\/\/randomwebsite.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/wpforms\/8231-9dfa327b1cf628635799d85de588101b\/test1.pdf","value_raw":[{"name":"test.pdf","value":"http:\/\/randomwebsite.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/wpforms\/8231-9dfa327b1cf628635799d85de588101b\/test1.pdf","file":"test1.pdf","file_original":"test.pdf","ext":"pdf","attachment_id":0,"id":15,"type":"application\/pdf"}],"id":15,"type":"file-upload","style":"modern"}
```

here I want to replace "http://randomwebsite.com" with "https://rightwebsite.me"
I tried this query:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET fields = REPLACE(fields, 'http:\/\/randomwebsite.com', 'https:\/\/rightwebsite.me')
WHERE fields LIKE '%"http:\/\/randomwebsite.com%';
```

I even tried using JSON_EXTRACT but I got this error:

```
#1305 - FUNCTION 111111_wp2.JSON_EXTRACT does not exist
```

but it didnt work. Can someone please help me as to how I can update a nested json in phpmyadmin?

Comment: try `UPDATE mytable
SET fields = REPLACE(fields, 'http:\/\/randomwebsite.com', 'https:\/\/rightwebsite.me')
WHERE fields LIKE '%http:\/\/randomwebsite.com%';`

Comment: it says 0 rows affected

Comment: do the same query again, but without the `LIKE '%http:\/\/randomwebsite.com%'`

Comment: is your `fields` column `text`, `varchar` or `json` ?

Comment: it works. I just had to it without the "\/\/" so i individually did  randomwebsite and http to https

Answer (score 0):

the first step you must exit from safe mode in the MySQL

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE mytable
SET `fields` = REPLACE(fields, 'http:\/\/randomwebsite.com', 'https:\/\/rightwebsite.me')
WHERE `fields` like '%http:\/\/randomwebsite.com%' ;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

then u can modify rows in the MySQL